# How to inject server variable to a client side js/html file

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, web-services, jersey

How can a Javascript variable set on a server(via properties file) be injected to an Angular js/JavaScript app?

There is a Java Jersey application that has client files (js, HTML, CSS, etc.) under the /src/main/webapp folder and there is a javascript variable that I would want to set before it gets served to the client. For example , please consider the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var serverHost = "<%serverHost%>";
    </script>
```

How can I replace the value of "<%serverHost%>" String with a value of my choice that will be evaluated at runtime? Preferably via properties.

The goal of this is that the client has Rest calls and the URL cannot be relative and has to be full because the application will be accessed via a different/middle man server, so ultimately the rest calls need to reach the originated host server. The value is need via a properties file so the application/same build can work on different environments.

Would appreciate any ideas.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve needs server side rendering.
In your case, for example,
You can retrieve the host URL from the properties file on the server side, pass it to the view using the controller, and in the view, using JSP tags, generate an HTML for which the serverHost variable is dynamically set

HOWEVER....

As you are using AngularJS, this type of rendering is clearly against Angular's philosophy.

You can create a constant in angular, 

`angular.module('myApp').constant('SERVER_URL', 'http://localhost:8000/');`

You can set the value of this constant during the build.

OR

You can create a simple API where you'll retrieve the host url value from the properties file, preferably in JSON format, then you can simply call that API to set this constant value.